# Running worker file in a loop gives error for nodeJs application

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads, node-promisify

When I am running a worker file inside a nodeJs application in a loop it gives error as :

```
Module did not self-register: '/server/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/bin/napi-v3/linux/x64/onnxruntime_binding.node'.
```

Here is my code:

```
const MyPomise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker("../server/workers/create.js", {
      workerData: { MessageList: listToSend }
    });
    worker.on("message", resolve);
    worker.on("error", reject);
  });
  const Data = await MyPomise;
```

Note: Above code is running worker file for the first time but giving error when running this in loop or requesting to run on second request in controller file.

Comment: I just noticed something: `MyPromise` is not a Promise, as you already await it.

Comment: @MarioSantini i checked removing await before MyPromise...still getting same issue

Comment: I thin it will be easier if you provide a minimal viable example that reproduce your issue. I attempted to do that with a trivial worker, but didn't had the same error. You shoul at least include the for loop in the code example.

Comment: @MarioSantini Actually this code i am running in a controller where multiple request are coming (I am not using loop in this case). But I am able to return the response for the first call, and getting error for the next request onwards. Same error I am getting if i used in loop at different place(My second use case).

Comment: Seems like issue with my package which I am importing in create.js(my worker file) is not loading second time because of some issue. Otherwise worker_thread is working fine.